# PostgreSQL doesn't ask for password

Tags: postgresql

I downloaded a PostgreSQL binary(9.4), ran initdb and executed the sql file which includes table creation statements. Of course, created a schema(FIRST) and a role(firstuser).

```
psql -d postgres -U firstuser -p 5433
psql (9.4.5)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 winname    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 firstuser  |                                                | {}
```

## pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

There is no 'postgres' role.

## Role creation

```
CREATE ROLE firstuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'userpassword' 
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

Starting PostgreSQL server by using a windows service.
Database itself works well.

The problem is:
Database doesn't ask for the password of 'firstuser' role.
I don't want the window user(wine) to see the tables of the firstuser, and login should provide a password to use 'firstuser' role and to find the tables of the relevant schema(first_schema).

How can I accomplish this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your environment variables, have you set PGPASSWORD? or check yout .pgpass file.

Comment: There is no .pgpass file, and with 'set' command in Command Prompt, I don't see PGPASSWORD env variable.

Comment: Oh..Sorry. There is a pgpass.conf file in %APPDATA% directory. Now it asks for password...Thank you.